# How to find an array larger than 0, in typeorm?

Tags: typeorm

Hi this is how my Postgres looks like

header is exampleHeader

[{test: 'hi'}] **full**

null **empty**

How do I filter andWhere to take out any results that are not full?

I tried the following:

```
const res = await this.testRepository
        .createQueryBuilder('ts')
        .where('ts.user_id = :id', { id })
        .andWhere('ts.exampleHeader >: num', { num: 0 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const res = await this.testRepository
        .createQueryBuilder('ts')
        .where('ts.user_id = :id', { id })
        .andWhere(`jsonb_array_length(ts.exampleHeader) >0`);
```

The above worked for me